# c# returning a string from sql 2005

Tags: c#, string

Ok,

I have a string in a sql table like this

```
hello /r/n this is a test /r/n new line.
```

When i retrieve this string using c# for a textbox using multiline i expect the escape chars to be newlines.

But they are not and what happens is i get the line exactly as it is above.

It seems that the string returned from the table is taken as literal but i want the newlines!

How do i get this to work?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: The string should be 
hello \r\n this is a test \r\n new line.
i got the escape chars the wrong way round, i am still getting the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things like "\n" (not "/n" by the way) are escape characters in *programming languages*, not inherently in text. (In particular, they're programming-language dependent.)

If you want to make

```
hello\r\nthis is a test\r\nnew line
```

format as

```
hello
this is a test
new line
```

you'll need to do the parsing yourself, replacing "\r" with carriage return, "\n" with newline etc, handling "\" as a literal backslash etc. I've typically found that a simple parser which just remembers whether or not the previous character was a backslash is good enough for most purposes. Something like this:

```
static string Unescape(string text)
{
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(text.Length);
    bool escaping = false;
    foreach (char c in text)
    {
        if (escaping)
        {
           // We're not handling \uxxxx etc
           escaping = false;
           switch(c)
           {
               case 'r': builder.Append('\r'); break;
               case 'n': builder.Append('\n'); break;
               case 't': builder.Append('\t'); break;
               case '\\': builder.Append('\\'); break;
               default:
                   throw new ArgumentException("Unhandled escape: " + c);
           }
        }
        else
        {
           if (c == '\\')
           {
               escaping = true;
           }
           else
           {
               builder.Append(c);
           }
        }
    }
    if (escaping)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Unterminated escape sequence");
    }
    return builder.ToString();
}
```

There are more efficient ways of doing it (skipping from backslash to backslash and appending whole substrings of non-escaped text, basically) but this is simple.

Answer (score 3):

/ is not the escape character, \ is. What you need is:

hello \r\n this is a test \r\n new line.

Comment: sorry my error, the string is hello \r\n this is a test \r\n new line.

Still get the same issue!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with my SQLite database the other day. Users are able to enter multi-line text into a textbox, and when it's inserted into the database, it goes in like:

```
"This is \r\n a multiline test"
```

It was coming out of `System.Data.SQLite` as:

```
"This is \\r\\n a multiline test"
```

I ended up using:

```
String.Replace("\\r","\r").Replace("\\n","\n")
```

to replace each of the escaped characters, which formatted the text properly when displayed in either a multi-line textbox or label.

Comment: What happens if someone wants to enter "old\new" which would presumably end up as "old\\new" in the database? :)

Comment: Good point - something I hadn't thought of :) Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to use System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode on the string before putting it in the TextBox.

```
 textBox.Value = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(myString);
```

Comment: @Stuart, sure, why not? This helper function exists expecially for encoding/decoding html strings. HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(..), HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(..)

Answer (score 0):

I do not see why a Parser is required in this instance, given that the language in question is C# and I assume that the OS is 32-bit Windows which treats `\r\n` as the NewLine character.

The following simple code (Windows app) works for me:

```
string s = "hello \r\n this is a test \r\n new line.";

// Set Multiline to True.
textBox1.Multiline = true;

// Expand the height of the textbox to be able to view the full text.
textBox1.Height = 100;
textBox1.Text = s;
```

The textbox shows text as:

```
hello
 this is a test 
 new line.
```

Comment: The programming language is C#, but the text isn't coming from a C# source file - it's coming from a database. Your case has a parser in as well - the C# compiler.

Comment: @Cerebrus - I think my post might explain why your code example works correctly.

Comment: No doubt possible, but that is the OP's responsibility to provide accurate information, not leave us guessing.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue here is that the string as seen by the user is

hello \r\n this is a test \r\n new line.

while the C# code sees it as

```
"hello \\r\\n this is a test \\r\\n new line."
```

A much simpler solution would be the following

```
s = Regex.Replace(s, @"\\\\", @"\");
```

which replaces @"\\" with @"\". Don't be confused by the regex match pattern, the \ has to be escaped in the match but not the replacement.